# Goals Firing on Ajax Confirmation Pages

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I am trying to track goals firing using Google Analytics, and I am running into issues with tracking actual confirmation pages that are AJAX calls. The confirmation page isn't a URL exactly, but a .php file which is loaded in AJAX. I can't figure out for the life of me why goals aren't able to fire using an AJAX call, but I can easily track a URL.

Here is all the information I have regarding the goals, including the goals, and actual code and the landing page itself (https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1uUjX5wWOpy9w85fpocIz32gMIWvZSQzSG8WCBDSq4DA).

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you're doing, how the code runs, and how the Goal is configured in Google Analytics?

Comment: sure, i have edited the post to include a google doc with the specifics. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, the URL that Google Analytics tracks is, by default, determined by what the browser detects (specifically, `location.pathname+location.search`). So, the filename of the php file that is loaded via AJAX is not relevant to Google Analytics, since by default, your trackPageview call will just send the URL that the browser shows (without the domain or  anchor values).

Google Analytics allows you to pass a custom URL as the path, as the second parameter of trackPageview.

So, in your confirmation page, you need to switch the `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);` to be

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/ed-JUNE-confirm']);
```

Now, there are other things that are confusing (for example, the multiple plain pageview calls on the same page), but, fundamentally, to 'trigger' the goal you need to send a pageview that has a head-match for your Goal URL, and use these virtual pageviews to accomplish it.